# Nested Loops Trouble

Tags: python, loops

I am doing this birthday problem for my statistics class which entails checking the probability of anyone sharing the same birthday. For 23 people, I should be getting probability of 0.5. I did 10k of trials but my probability is 0.7. It has to be the code which I tediously checked and debugged.

```
import random
import numpy as np

n=10_000
m=23
a= np.random.randint(1,365, size=(n,m))
b=[]
count=1

j=0
while j<n:
    i=0
    while i<m:
        k=i+1
        while k<m:      
            if a[j][i]==a[j][k]: 
                b.append(count) 
            k+=1
            
        i+=1 
    j+=1

z=(len(b)/n)
print("Probability = ",z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep counting overlapping birthdays even if you already found one for a trial.

Comment: You could expand on this a bit more, but your brief answer nonetheless correctly identifies the core of the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is that in each experiment, after finding a pair that share the same birthday, you keep going and can count one for each additional pair also. You really want to `break` from the inner loop, but because it would involve jumping out of two levels of loops, which is not easy to achieve with `break`, it will be more convenient to `return` from a function instead.

Also tidying up a bit by replacing your `while` loops with `for` loops and just using an integer counter rather than a list of `1` values, gives the following:

```
import random
import numpy as np

def share_birthday(birthdays):
    m = len(birthdays)
    for i in range(m):
        for k in range(i + 1, m):
            if birthdays[i] == birthdays[k]:
                return 1
    return 0

n = 10000
m = 23
a = np.random.randint(1, 365, size=(n,m))

count = 0
for j in range(n):
    if share_birthday(a[j]):
        count += 1
z = count / n
print("Probability = ",z)
```

and on a single test this got the result:

```
Probability =  0.5101
```

For comparison, here is a direct calculation of the probability (not dependent on Monte Carlo approach):

```
p = 1.
m = 23
days = 365

for i in range(m):
    p *= (days - i) / days

q = 1 - p

print('Probability = ', q)
```

which gives:

```
Probability =  0.5072972343239857
```

---

**Addendum** - after discussion in the comments, it seems that you would like to see an example of how you can `break` out of nested loops.  The answer is that you need to set a flag when you break from the inner loop, which you can test in order to decide whether to break also from the outer loop.  Like this (again using `for` loops for conciseness, but the same would apply also to the original `while` loops)...

```
import random
import numpy as np

n = 10000
m = 23
a = np.random.randint(1,365, size=(n,m))
count = 0

for j in range(n):
    match = False
    for i in range(m):
        for k in range(i+1, m):
            if a[j][i] == a[j][k]:
                count += 1
                match = True
                break
        if match:
            break
            
z = count / n
print("Probability = ", z)
```

Again, this should report a probability close to 0.5.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I hope this all makes sense, and you understand why I suggest using `return` from a function - a `break` would only exit from the inner loop but you want to break from of two of the three loops.

Comment: Well, it does but to be honest, I wish there was more than just one way of doing this. Nested loops seem to be useless here...

Comment: @Thomas you are going to need the nested loops because you need to loop through combinations of two people selected from the class. You could perhaps use `itertools.combinations` but effectively that is hiding the looping out of sight inside a module -- it still needs to be done though.

Comment: Well, what I meant is I wish there was a way to fix my version of nested loops vs just being limited to this one approach with using a function with nested loops.

Comment: @Thomas Well you *can* break from nested loops but you need to set a flag that you test in order to decide whether to break from the outer loop after you break form the inner one. Is this enough to go on, or would you like me to add it to the answer to show you how?

Comment: Sure, I'd like to see it. Btw, thanks again for helping out.

Comment: @Thomas Okay, I've added an addendum with this information.

Comment: This is great! Thanks again. I just wanted to use what I already had vs starting a new approach with the function. I owe you :)